# lock_guard causing the line of code to be hung

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, mutex, boost-mutex

I have the following code where I am using lock_guard for a named mutex so that the mutex lock gets released when the execution of code is finished (including exceptions thrown)

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main()
{
    named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "some_name");

    boost::lock_guard<named_mutex> guard(mutex);
    // Do other things
}
```

But the code hangs on the boost::lock_guard guard(mutex); and does not proceed to next line. Why?

Comment: I think before you ask a question you need to figure out what language you are in, this is obviously not C#

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](https://www.ideone.com/cy5oyt)

Comment: weird. I definitely cannot reach the next line in Visual Studio

Comment: I just ran this with VS 2015 and had no issues with the sample code at the link with an old version of boost (1.61).

Comment: Maybe you killed the process while the mutex was locked. Don't know what would happen in that case.

Comment: I am running with Visual Studio 2017, boost 1.65. The process continues to run, does not get killed but it does not proceed to any other code after the lock_guard line of code